# USB-C to Ethernet adapter – network connection is unstable

Tags: linux, network-adapter, dell-xps

I am using Fedora 32 KDE spin on a 4 year old Dell XPS 9550. This laptop does not have an ethernet port. I purchased 4 different USB C to Ethernet adapters. But only the cheapest one gives me a stable wired connection. All the others work fine for a while and then I get occasional notifications of the wired network toggling between activation and deactivation. After some time this toggling becomes very frequent. To make sure that that there is no fault in the adapters I asked a friend to use the worst adapter on his Windows laptop. He has been using it for past two days without any issues! My question is can this be a Linux vs Windows issue? I don’t think my USB c port has a problem because one of the adpaters works fine. Is it possible that that this can be a GNOME vs KDE issue? Will reinstalling Fedora Gnome or Windows make a difference?

Comment: could be some form USB low-power mode/power saving functionality. I would expect that to involve both OS and mainboard capabilities

Comment: Why not try another Linix distro, e.g. Ubuntu, from a live USB flash drive on your own setup? No need to install. If the connection doesn't fail, you've isolated the issue to Fedora setup; if it also becomes flaky, then it's hardware. An easy check (~1/2 hour to create and to run from the USB, total).

Comment: @DrMoishe Thank you for the suggestion. Live CD is a good idea. I had installed Debian KDE to check if it is a Fedora KDE issue but I got the same problem in Debian as well. So I will try some GNOME live usb.